# Summation circuit using an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I have two voltage sources V1, V2

I want my output voltage to be 4V2 - V1

Im using a single op-amp and up to 4 resistors: (Only one is shown here and It's set as 10k Ohm) I can add 3 more.

[image]

I know how to create functions where I sum only negative voltages ( -V1 -4V2 - V3 ...)
But I have no idea how to execute what I mentioned above,
any help would be appreciated !
thanks.

My try:[image]

Which sorts out the -V1 part of my output, but gives only 2*V2. I don't know how to procceed.

Comment: Edward, I wonder what is the name of the simulator used for the schematics above? (I also posted an answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I don't know how to proceed.*

This should work if I'm not too mistaken: -

[image]

[image]

If you *need* to use 4 resistors then 2 parallel 10k resistors = 5k. Now, all resistors are the same value too.

Comment: This indeed works for me, I'm Still trying to figure out the thought proccess which led you to the solution. thank you!

Comment: @EdwardJosef ah the good-old thought process!!! I'm unsure myself other than to say "experience".

Comment: I'd add a 5k resistor in series to the negative input to compensate for DC offset.

Comment: @F.Heisenberg I think you mean the non-inverting input (only needed for crappy op-amps with poor input bias currents).

Comment: Sorry of course I meant the non inverting input

Answer (score 0):

An inverting opamp sums inputs. I turned around the inputs so that the inverted output is positive.

[image: Op-amp circuit schematic]